# Stack images on top of each other instead on slick slider

Tags: jquery, css, open-source, slideshow, slick.js

I understand that slick is a carousel slider but I would love to stick to this particular library for the [site I am working on](http://www.standishsalongoods.com/marfa-salon-styling-station-in-black).

Here's an image of what I would like to try with slick.js:

[image: standish salon goods]

Are there any built in ways to override this or best practices to try to override the slider view? If not, are there any good, open source, well supported libraries like slick out there that can easily do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm totally new to slick, so I have no idea when they added the feature, but there is an option named `row` and another which is `slidesPerRow`. I do not know how the last row would look like (centered, left aligned?) but that should do what you need.

Detailed documentation can be found here:

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks! fortunately, we found a more sensible design solution but I will have to check this out when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0):

add `clear: both` to the slick bar elements like this (in the latest CSS file you load in the page):

```
.slick-slide {
    clear: both !important;
 }
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm trying to make the slides stay bounded to their container and then pool vertically into another row, similar to the amazon.com product presentation